# Why I can't open an application with ssh?

Tags: macos, ssh

I have a problem to open an application with the Terminal on mac.
I'm using a Macbook (running on High Sierra 10.13.6) and want to open an application on a remote computer using ssh. This remote computer is a Imac (MacOS Catalina).

I try to launch an application using the following command line :

> open -a TeamViewer

but it fails to open and returns the following error message:

> LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/TeamViewer.app with error -610.

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this problem ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you expecting the application's window to open on your MacBook? `ssh` doesn't tunnel the macOS GUI.

Comment: Some background: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SECTION9

Comment: @chepner : Thanks for your reply. No, I don't expect that, I just want launch the application on the remote computer, such that I have the possibility to open a teamViewer session between my laptop and this remote computer. 
The command I mention above (open -a TeamViewer ) used to be working until I recently restarted the remote computer.

Comment: @Ken Thomases Thanks for your reply. Sorry but I don't understand where I should start looking.

Comment: @Bibash OK. I think the issue may still be that `ssh` logs you in with a process that doesn't have access to the GUI. Either using something other than `ssh` (like [Apple Remote Desktop](https://support.apple.com/remote-desktop)), or use AppleScript rather than `open` to request that TeamViewer be launched.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to run the Teamviewer Gui application, either as a different user to the currently logged in user or no user is logged in at all so the application doesn't have permission or there is no user display server to connect to.

If you've installed TeamViewer it should also install the appropriate LaunchDaemons and start the service when the machine starts.

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service.plist
```

In this file I find the command to start the teamviewer service:

```
/Applications/TeamViewer.app/Contents/MacOS/TeamViewer_Service -Module Full
```

When I run this command (you may want to background or nohup it) I can see the server process running:

```
77890 ttys000    0:00.34 /Applications/TeamViewer.app/Contents/MacOS/TeamViewer_Service -Module Full
```

Depending on how teamviewer is configured on that machine.  It may listen for LAN connections and/or establish a connection to the teamviewer cloud servers.

You can use netstat or lsof to verify this.

Mark

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are trying to open TeamViewer as root. I'm assuming the root user doesn't have a window manager open.

You could log into the Mac as root via the Mac login screen and then try ssh into the machine as root and try to open TeamViewer again but it would be easier and less bat5h1t if you just used w to see who's logged in, then login [username-thats-logged-in] then open TeamViewer.

hope this helps.

Comment: Applications started by root can connect to the desktop regardless of who is logged into the desktop.  Other normal privileged users cannot open an application on a different users desktop.